# Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{x^ny^m}{x^2+y^2}}=0$ if $n+m>2$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I wrote a proof for this, but it doesn't require that $n+m>2$, only that $n+m\neq 2$. So my question is, what is wrong with my proof? Note that for the question, $n$ and $m$ are non-negative integers.

*Proof*. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and suppose that $\delta>\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>0$. Now observe that
$$\left|\frac{x^ny^m}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|=\frac{\left|x^ny^m\right|}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{\left(|x|^2\right)^{n/2}\left(|y|^2\right)^{m/2}}{x^2+y^2}$$
Clearly, $|x|^2=x^2\leq x^2+y^2$ and $|y|^2=y^2\leq x^2+y^2$. Thus
$$\frac{\left(|x|^2\right)^{n/2}\left(|y|^2\right)^{m/2}}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{n/2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{m/2}}{x^2+y^2}=\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{(n+m-2)/2}<\delta^{n+m-2}$$
Choose $\delta=\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{n+m-2}}$. Then
$$\left|\frac{x^ny^m}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|<\delta^{n+m-2}=\varepsilon,$$
as desired.

So, obviously $n+m\neq2$, but I don't see why I can't have $n+m<2$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $k<0$ and $0<x<\epsilon^k,$ it is not true that $x^{1/k}<\epsilon$ For example. If $k=-1/2:$ then $1/2<1^{-1/2}$ but $(1/2)^{-2}=4>1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you use
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta\ \Longrightarrow   \bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\bigr)^{n+m-2} < \delta^{n+m-2},
$$
which relies on the fact that the function
$$
t \longmapsto t^{n+m-2}
$$
is monotonically increasing. This is false if the exponent is negative, i.e. like picture the graph of $1/x = x^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

I would use polar coordinates representation for $x$ and $y$.
$$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta$$
The limit of $(x,y)\to 0$ is equivalent to $r\to 0$, independent of $\theta$.
Then you have $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^n\cos^n\theta r^m\sin^m\theta}{r^2}=\cos^m\theta\sin^n\theta\lim_{r\to0}r^{m+n-2}$$
If $m+n-2>0$ the limit is $0$. If $m+n<2$ then the last limit is infinite. If $m+n=2$, then the last limit is $1$, but the overall value depends on the path $(\theta)$, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: I would too, and I did for part (a) of the question, but this section required it be an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof.